# Testing requests that redirect with mocha/supertest in node

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, supertest

I can't seem to get the following integration test to pass in an express project using [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/), [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest), and [should](https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js/) (and coffeescript).

---

**The test**

```
should  = require('should')
request = require('supertest')
app     = require('../../app')

describe 'authentication', ->
  describe 'POST /sessions', ->
    describe 'success', (done) ->
      it 'displays a flash', (done) ->
        request(app)
          .post('/sessions')
          .type('form')
          .field('user', 'username')
          .field('password', 'password')
          .end (err, res) ->
            res.text.should.include('logged in')
            done()
```

---

**Relevant application code**

```
app.post '/sessions', (req, res) ->
  req.flash 'info', "You are now logged in as #{req.body.user}"
  res.redirect '/login'
```

---

**Failure**

```
1) authentication POST /sessions success displays a flash:
   AssertionError: expected 'Moved Temporarily. Redirecting to //127.0.0.1:3456/login' to include 'logged in'
```

---

Obviously, the application code doesn't do anything useful. I'm just trying to get the test to pass.

Putting the expectation (`res.text.should.include('logged in')`) outside the end function and inside the `expect` function yields the same results. I've also tried a variation of the function calls, for example removing the `.type('form')` call, and using `.send(user: 'username', password: 'password')` instead of the two `.field()` calls.

If it means anything, sending a curl POST request to the the app when it's running locally yields the same output (`Moved Temporarily. Redirecting to //127.0.0.1:3456/login`)

I have a feeling this is a trivial error. Possibly something I'm forgetting in the application code or the test code.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1:** It's also worth noting that when clicking the submit button in the browser I get the expected results (a flash message).

**EDIT 2:** Further investigation shows the output of *any* redirect results in the `Moved Temporarily. Redirecting to ...` response body. This makes me wonder if there is a problem in the way I'm exporting the app in app.js.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001183/how-to-authenticate-supertest-requests-with-passport/37609721#37609721

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this page, the answer to this question is pretty simple. The `Moved Temporarily.` response body is what is returned from supertest. See [the issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/21) for more details.

To summarize, I ended up doing something like this.

```
should  = require('should')
request = require('supertest')
app     = require('../../app')

describe 'authentication', ->
  describe 'POST /sessions', ->
    describe 'success', ->
      it 'redirects to the right path', (done) ->
        request(app)
          .post('/sessions')
          .send(user: 'username', password: 'password')
          .end (err, res) ->
            res.header['location'].should.include('/home')
            done()
```

Just check that the response header `location` is what you expect it to be. Testing for flash messages and view specific integration tests should be done using another method.

Comment: ...what other method?

Comment: I am here specifically because I was trying to do "Testing for flash messages and view specific integration tests should be done using another method."

Comment: In addition to checking the location in the header, you should check that res.statusCode is 302 (redirect).

Answer (score 35):

There is built-in assertion for this in `supertest`:

```
should  = require('should')
request = require('supertest')
app     = require('../../app')

describe 'authentication', ->
  describe 'POST /sessions', ->
    describe 'success', ->
      it 'redirects to the right path', (done) ->
        request(app)
          .post('/sessions')
          .send(user: 'username', password: 'password')
          .expect(302)
          .expect('Location', '/home')
          .end(done)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
describe 'authentication', ->
  describe 'POST /sessions', ->
    describe 'success', (done) ->
      it 'displays a flash', (done) ->
        request(app)
          .post('/sessions')
          .type('form')
          .field('user', 'username')
          .field('password', 'password')
          .redirects(1)
          .end (err, res) ->
            res.text.should.include('logged in')
            done()
```

The `redirects()` will follow the redirect so you can do your usual view tests.

Comment: This may be an old post but the .redirects(1) worked beautifully for me to resolve a redirect error while testing. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to write some integration tests for requests that redirected as well, and found a good example by the author of the module himself [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/14#issuecomment-24024540).

In TJ's example, he's using chaining, so I used something like that as well.

Consider a scenario in which a logged-in user is *redirected* to the home page when he or she logs out.

```
it('should log the user out', function (done) {
  request(app)
    .get('/logout')
    .end(function (err, res) {
      if (err) return done(err);
      // Logging out should have redirected you...
      request(app)
        .get('/')
        .end(function (err, res) {
          if (err) return done(err);
          res.text.should.not.include('Testing Tester');
          res.text.should.include('login');
          done();
        });
    });
});
```

Depending on how many redirects you have, you might have to nest a few callbacks, but TJ's example should suffice.