# How to login each time before running a test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, passport.js

I am a newbie in testing in Javascript and trying to test my NodeJS backend using mocha and chai.
How all of my routes are filled with a middleware which does not allow people to go forward if they aren't logged in.

Something like this

```
app.post('/user/analytics/driverdata', checkauth, function(req, res) {
        analytics.driverData(req, res);
});
```

where `checkauth` is

```
var checkauth = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("In checkauth");
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        next();
    } else {
        console.log("Doesn't authenticate");
        res.status(401);
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.end(JSON.stringify({
            'success': false
        }));
    }
};
```

The isAuthenticated parameter is attached to request by PassportJS, when it deserializes a request.
What I want to do is write a test for

```
app.post('/user/analytics/driverdata', checkauth, function(req, res) {
            analytics.driverData(req, res);
});
```

this API. in which I am failing as I am not logged in hence unable to reach there.
So I wrote a beforeEach to login the user `beforeEach it`. It goes like this.

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var request = require('superagent');

beforeEach(function(done){
        //login into the system
        request
        .post("http:localhost:5223/user/authenticate/login")
        .send({username : "saras.arya@gmail.com", password : "saras"})
        .end(function assert(err, res){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            done();
        }
        else{
            done();
        }
    });
});
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong and the internet has failed me. Any help to point out where am I going wrong  will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing a lot of stuff and fidgeting around I think I finally cracked it. It would be harsh not to mention [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001183/how-to-authenticate-supertest-requests-with-passport) which introduced me to the concept of an agent. Which helped me crack this. 
Inside your describe block, or probably before the block you can have the following `it`.

```
var superagent = require('superagent');
var agent = superagent.agent();
it('should create a user session successfully', function(done) {
       agent
       .post('http://localhost:5223/user/authenticate/login')
       .send({
              username: 'whatever@example.com',
              password: 'ssh-its-a-secret'
        })
        .end(function(err, res) {
             console.log(res.statusCode);
             if (expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200))
                 return done();
             else {
                 return done(new Error("The login is not happening"));
                    }
                });
        });
```

the agent variable holds the cookies for you, which are then used by PassportJS to authenticate you.

here is how you do it. So the agent variable is inside a `describe`. In the same `describe` inside another `it`.

```
it("should test analytics controller", function(done) {
agent.post('http://localhost:5040/user/analytics/driverData')
        .send({
            startDate: "",
            endDate: "",
            driverId: ""
        })
        .end(function(err, res) {
            if(!err)
            done();
        });
});
```

This function passes like a charm. This was one complete documentation that was missing.