# Testing express passport application with mocha and chai

Tags: express, mocha.js, passport.js, postman, chai

I'm trying to test my application with mocha, chai and chai-http. When I test the login, I can't seem to log in no matter what I try. I've tried in Postman and gotten the same result.

I've seen many answers along the lines of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37154183/225134) but I've had no success with them.

Is Passport doing something that's preventing successful login? I can log in from the browser with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078569/seem-to-have-the-wrong-content-type-when-posting-with-chai-http) post and from tinkering with the settings in Postman. Adding the content type `x-www-form-urlencoded` seemed to be the key.

```
it('should redirect to dashboard on successful login', function(done) {
    chai.request('http://localhost:3000')
      .post('/login')
      .set('Token', 'text/plain')
      .set('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
      .type('form')
      .send('grant_type=password')
      .send('username=bobby')
      .send('password=abc123')
      .end(function(err, res) {
        res.should.have.status(200);
        expect(res).to.redirectTo('http://localhost:3000/user/dashboard');
        done();
      });
  });
```