# Unable to send authenticated request in tests using Jest, Supertest, Passport, Koa2

Tags: node.js, jestjs, supertest, koa2

Despite my best attempts to correctly write test code to authenticate a request agent in Setup blocks or previous describe/it blocks, any request I make from the agent in subsequent describe/it blocks never completes as 200.

Example code:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const server = require('../server');

let agent = request.agent(server);
let fakePerson = null;

beforeEach(async (done) => {
  fakePerson = await Person.createMock();

  agent.post(‘/login’)
       .send({
           email: ‘test@user.com’,
           password: ‘password’
        })
        .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            done();
        });
});

describe('GET /users/:id', () => {
    it ('renders user profile', () => {
      return agent
        .get(`/users/${fakePerson.id}`)
        .expect(200)
    });
});
```

I thought it might have something to do with how I was forming the async calls syntactically. But after trying different ways of returning the login call in the `beforeEach` block using `return`, `.end()` syntax, even async/await, I've determined (ie given up) that the code must be composed properly. Could it be something else?

Referenced articles/resources:

- [How to authenticate Supertest requests with Passport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001183/how-to-authenticate-supertest-requests-with-passport)
- https://medium.com/@juha.a.hytonen/testing-authenticated-requests-with-supertest-325ccf47c2bb
- https://gist.github.com/joaoneto/5152248
- https://medium.com/@bill_broughton/testing-with-authenticated-routes-in-express-6fa9c4c335ca
- https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/46

Package versions:

- "koa": "^2.4.1"
- "koa-passport": "^4.0.1"
- "passport-json": "^1.2.0"
- "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
- "supertest": "^3.0.0"
- "jest": "^22.1.3"

Comment: came across most of your articles/resources when trying to figure out a very similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60914997/middleware-must-be-a-function-for-koa-passport-testing-using-jest-typescript . Are you able to shed any light on it please?

Comment: @HarryLincoln Apologies, I haven't touched this code or worked on a similar issue since then so I can't be of help at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me all the same @internetross !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took some time stepping through my auth code during test runs and couldn't see any obvious problem. Then I had a thought: what if the request itself was ill formed. Turns out I was right! Inspecting the `set-cookie` header in the Supertest response headers I saw:

```
[ 'koa:sess=eyJwYXNzcG9ydCI6eyJ1c2VyIjoxfSwiX2V4cGlyZSI6MTUyMTIyODg0NTU5OSwiX21heEFnZSI6ODY0MDAwMDB9; path=/; httponly,koa:sess.sig=EEZzgcg3bx8bm_FXRMobrr8_Yts; path=/; httponly' ]
```

This looked a little suspicious as a single string, which led me to some more googling where I discovered that there were differences in the way that cookie headers were being set for Mocha and Jest users as global state on the Supertest agent instance. See: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3547#issuecomment-302541653. Folks using Mocha had no trouble authenticating, while Jest users did. Turns out there is a [bug](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3547#issuecomment-302541653) with Jest globals that is causing the cookie to come in as a single string rather than an array of separate strings for each cookie--which is what Supertest needs to format the request properly.

Here is a workaround based on the code in the question where we correctly parse the buggy Jest string to a scoped variable for the cookie/session data inside the Setup block:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const server = require('../server');

let agent = request.agent(server);
let fakePerson = null;
let session = null;

beforeEach(async () => {
  fakePerson = await Person.createMock();

  agent.post(‘/login’)
       .send({
           email: fakePerson.email,
           password: fakePerson.password’
        })
        .then(res => {
            session = res
               .headers['set-cookie'][0]
               .split(',')
               .map(item => item.split(';')[0])
               .join(';')
            expect(res.status).toEqual(200)
      });
});

describe('GET /users/:id', () => {
    it ('renders user profile', () => {
      return agent
        .get(`/users/${fakePerson.id}`)
        .set('Cookie', session)
        .expect(200)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get internetross's answer to work. Finally after lots of sleuthing, I found this: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3547#issuecomment-397183207.

I had to replace

```
session = response.headers['set-cookie'][0]
               .split(',')
               .map(item => item.split(';')[0])
               .join('; ')
```

with

```
  response.headers['set-cookie'][0]
    .split(',')
    .map(item => item.split(';')[0])
    .forEach(c => agent.jar.setCookie(c));
```

Big sigh.